Expo app Metro waiting on http://localhost:8081
when i run my expo app by npx expo start -c i get this :
› Metro waiting on http://localhost:8081
› Scan the QR code above to open the project in a development build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/start
› Using development build
› Press s │ switch to Expo Go
› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web
› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› Press o │ open project code in your editor
› Press ? │ show all commands
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
but i am not working on the localhost
i tried to uninstall expo and reinstall but the same thing
